# Background-size is not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This [site](http://detskysvetmasa.cz/) is using a zigzag border. It's working fine in Chrome. But the zigzag is not showing in IE. I'm using IE 11.

Answer (score 2):

as IE9+ supports `background-size`, this shouldn't be the issue.

The problem is the body has no height. Giving `<html>` a 100% height worked for me. or add clearfix to your body.[example here](http://diywpblog.com/when-and-how-to-use-a-clearfix-css-tutorial/)

Comment: I've added height: 100% to html. But it still isn't working. :(